# Observer has null object, even though the object is instantiated right above

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this function in my app:

```
fun bindUI() = launch(Dispatchers.Main){
        val locationResults = locationViewModel.locationResponse
        val owner = viewLifecycleOwner

        locationResults.observe(owner, Observer {
            if (it == null) return@Observer

            // TODO: set loading icon to GONE

            initRecyclerView(it.features.toLocationSearchResultListItem())
        })
    }
```

This function is triggered when a certain button is pressed in the app.  When debugging the code, the locationResults field is set to a RoomTrackingLiveData object, but then when it gets to the if condition inside the observer, `it` is null, and it returns out of the function.  In this case `it` is of type `LocationSearchResponse!` and `locationViewModel.locationResponse` is of type `LiveData<out LocationSearchResponse>`

Why would `it` be null right after results are correctly retrieved from that variable just a few lines before?

Comment: The `LiveData<out LocationSearchResponse>` is not null, that says nothing about the values returned from that LiveData though.

Comment: So `it` being null means that the data itself could be null?

Comment: How would I be able to debug that to check the values?

Answer (score 0):

<s>Dispatcher.Main may be the UI thread, but the UI thread by itself does not have a view lifecycle like Activities and Fragments.</s>

You have to bind your viewmodel within a fragment or activity or viewLifecycleOwner is going to be null.

When you think about it it makes sense that this cannot work, because you could have say 5 fragments on screen at the same time. All of them run on the UI thread with seperate lifecycles. Witch of them do you propose viewLifecycleOwner should be referring to?

Since you said this runs on a button click. Just remove the coroutine and it should probably work.

There also is a lifecycle aware coroutine scope 'viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch' if you wish to use a coroutine and make it lifecycle aware. But I dont really see the point here. It is possible though and maybe there is a point and somebody can enlighten me. ^^

Seems like that's not the problem like @ianhanniballake suggested your LiveData's data might be null. You can get the data with the `locationResults.value` or when you debug your `locationResults` should have a field `mData`. That's is later your `it`.

Comment: This function is being called inside of a fragment.  Sorry, I should have clarified that.

Comment: Ok, good then does it work without the coroutine or the lifecycle aware coroutine?

Comment: Nope, still null

Comment: So it looks like the value is null.  I know that this is done asynchronously, so it makes sense that it might be null at some point, but it looks like whatever the observer is observing is never being updated, because it never gets called with anything other than a null value

Comment: I'm using ```@Query("select * from location_search_results WHERE `query` = :searchQuery")
    fun searchForLocation(searchQuery: String): LiveData<LocationSearchResponse>``` to query the db, and that returns a live tracking data object whose value is always null